# 'Moe' for short

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge, wordplay

We've always called him Moe, but it's been so long since I last heard his full name that I've since forgotten it... as his right-hand man, this won't do.

Moe's been on this Earth long enough to know the meaning of life. His clothing choice is a bit tacky; at our office parties, he always gets the lowest score. Maybe it's because he wears denim?
I heard he's started learning Japanese- to strengthen his aging mind, I guess. He's been asking me to join him at his weekend classes. I've told him time and time again that I refuse, but as old-time partners he knows ruthless hounding will break through my iron will eventually.
As aforementioned, his taste in style is a bit lacking... he owns a old, dusty silver van that he drives to work.

What's his full name?

I created a few more hints, if you need them:

> He used to be a technician.

> Moe's next door neighbor is a bit of a strange one. He goes by 'Wallas Stevenfore' even though the name on his ID card says 'Stanley Etun'. It's not my place to pry, though.

> I hear Moe is a bit color-blind. In fact, out of the 256 colors, there are roughly two dozen or so that he has a hard time with.

As a bonus question: There are four letters that have not been used. Arrange their Numbers in numerical order to create a passcode.

Comment: First puzzle, I think the tags are right- read the description of them, an' all. I believe everything else should be good to go, though.

Comment: Hey @iiiidk , welcome to Puzzling.SE, that looks like an interesting puzzle! Also, nicely done with the spoilered hints. Just one tip - people tend to prefer laying out the puzzle alone at first, and after a day or more, add one hint at a time. That way, it starts off harder, and gets a bit easier if people are still stumped after a couple of days.

Comment: I figured since they've got the hiding thing going on, I could drop them there until I get a notification. I'll keep them in a sticky note, then! EDIT: Realized the bonus question would need rewording, then.. I'll figure something out.

Comment: Oh, do note that users can see the edit history of a question, so my suggestion about progressive hints was for future questions, not this one. :-)

Comment: hmmm... I'll keep that in mind for future ones, then :)

Comment: Is this a real person? :-)

Comment: @Manoj  Not quite

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't have all the clues figured out, but I'm fairly sure the full name is...

> Molybdenum

Title

> Molybdenum has chemical symbol "Mo".

Moe's been on this Earth long enough to know the meaning of life.

> Atomic number 42, reference to hitchhikers guide to the galaxy.

His clothing choice is a bit tacky; at our office parties, he always gets the lowest score. Maybe it's because he wears denim?

> I suppose molybdenum is a tacky metal. Also it has "denum" in the name.

I heard he's started learning Japanese- to strengthen his aging mind, I guess.

> Japanese sounds like Manganese.

He's been asking me to join him at his weekend classes. I've told him time and time again that I refuse, but as old-time partners he knows ruthless hounding will break through my iron will eventually.

> "Iron will" is yet another reference to a metal.

As aforementioned, his taste in style is a bit lacking... he owns a old, dusty silver van that he drives to work

> Molybdenum as a material looks old, dusty, and silver.

Hint 1.

> Technetium

Hint 2.

> "Wallas Stevenfore" sounds similar to "Steven Wolfram". "Stanley Etun" sounds like a mixed up "Tungsten". The element is called Tungsten, although it is often called Wolfram.

Hint 3.

> 

---

OP's Edit:
Since the answer was almost completely found, here's the full walkthrough.
First Part:

> Molybdenum, or Moly B. Denum if you really want to make it a name. Atomic number 42, a movie reference as pointed out. His clothes are "TAcky", a reference to Tantalum, one of Mo's neighbors on the periodic table. TA has an atomic number of 73- a low score if you put it in the perspective of getting judged at a party! As mentioned, "denim" is a play on "denum".

Second Part:

> Manga is a type of graphic novel from Japan, a reference to Manganese, another one of Mo's neighboring elements and a hint found above. Perhaps the most obscure wordplay was on "RUTHless hounding", which references Ruthenium, an element that is below Iron, the next obvious reference. The "silver VAN" describes Vanadium, the final neighbor mentioned in the original post.

The Third Hint:

> The first two hints were found above. The third hint references "chroma", or color. It mentions that Mo cannot see "two dozen" colors- in other words, "24". Chromium has atomic number 24.

Bonus Question:

> Therefore, the elements that were mentioned were: Vanadium, Chromium, Manganese, Technetium, Tungsten, Tantalum, (and Ruthenium & Iron). These elements are all neighbors of Molybdenum, but there are two neighbors that were never mentioned: Niobium and Rhenium, atomic numbers 41 and 75. Thus the passcode would be 4175 or 1457 depending on how you interpreted "Numbers in numerical order".

Comment: Wondering whether Hint 2 is a reference to (ROT13) ghatfgra/jbysenz.

Comment: @Riley The hints were a bit cryptic, for sure. The additional hint I'll give is that each line is referencing something, but not necessarily Moe himself. You got his name, though! Check mark :)

Comment: @F1Krazy is correct for that hint, and thinking that way will reveal the rest of the hints, too. Good job :D

Comment: @iiiidk I think I've figured everything out except for the last hint.

Comment: Getting close! If you're going for the bonus question, then you can probably guess how many were referenced- so I'll say that the comment on Moe's "tacky" clothing refers to someone else. You got "denim" right. Iron is correct, and there is an equally obscure wordplay reference in that line. There is someone else who looks silver. All of these have something in common to Moe, which will allow you to guess who is missing for the bonus question. @Riley